# How can I keep a selection in a select after submit form by using jquery/struts2

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I'm trying to keep the drop down selections after submited the form. 
The problem is that s:select values ("server 1", "server 2"... for servers select tag and "amex", "liffe"... for markets select tag) are loaded always in the original way. Keep in mind that combos are loaded in the script and not in the server side. (I can't use session cookies).

I have tried with these options while loading (no one works properly):

- `$('#servers > option[value='seledtedServer']').attr('selected', 'selected');`
- `$('#servers.prepend($('', { value: val['ip'], text: val['name'] })); where val is equal to selectedServer. (Here  selectedServer ups in the combo but not to the header value as I want).
- `headerValue="%{#session.selectedServer}"` in the s:select tags, but I obtain the "ip", when I pretend to get the "name". I have tried here to modify the session value, but I couldn't.

index.jsp ------------->

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Connex </title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

            var data = [{"name":"server 1","ip":"10.10.10.1",
                            "markets":[{"name":"amex","ports":"02,17,18,19,20"},
                                       {"name":"liffe","ports":"03,05,06,07,08,25,26,27,28,29"},
                                       {"name":"lse","ports":"04,21,22,23,24"},
                                       {"name":"nasdaq","ports":"00,13,14,15,16"},
                                       {"name":"nyse","ports":"01,09,10,11,12"}]},
                        {"name":"server 2","ip":"10.10.10.2",
                            "markets":[{"name":"nyse","ports":"00,01,02,03,04,05"}]},
                        {"name":"server 3","ip":"10.10.10.3",
                            "markets":[{"name":"fxcm","ports":"00"}]}];

            $(window).load(function(){
                var selectedServer = '<%= session.getAttribute("selectedServer") %>'; // I get the "ip" but I pretended the "name"
                var selectedMarket = '<%= session.getAttribute("selectedMarket") %>'; // I get the "ports" but I pretended the "name"
                var $serverList = $('#servers');
                $.each(data, function(i, val){
                    $serverList.append($('<option />', { value: val['ip'], text: val['name'] }));
                });

                $('#servers').change(function() {
                    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
                    $.each(data, function(id, element) {
                        if (element['name'] == selected){
                            var $marketList = $('#markets');
                            $marketList.empty();
                            $.each(element['markets'], function(i, market){
                                $marketList.append($('<option />', { value: market['ports'], text: market['name'] }));
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }); 
            });
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Struts 2 - Connex</h2>
    <s:actionerror />
    <s:form action="ejecutar.action" namespace="/" method="post">

        <div id="serverList">
                <s:select label="Select server" 
                list="{}" 
                name="servers" id="servers" headerKey="-1" headerValue=""/>
        </div>


        <div id="marketList">
                <s:select label="Select market" 
                list="{}" 
                name="markets" id="markets" headerKey="-1" headerValue=""/>
        </div>

        <div id="cmd" >
                <s:textfield label="cmd" name="cmd" />
        </div>

        <s:submit value="Submit"/>

    </s:form>    
    <s:textarea name="result" id="result" cols="60" rows="30"/>
</body>
</html> 

------------------

action.java --------------->

    private String cmd;

    private String servers;
    private String markets;

    private String result;

    // For SessionAware
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String selectedServer;
    private String selectedMarket;

    public String ejecutar() throws Exception {

        session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put("selectedServer",(String)servers);
        session.put("selectedMarket",(String)markets);
```

---

Thanks in advance, all proposals a very apreciated.

Comment: Ok, I have found an answer which is $('#servers').val(selectedServer); after load the servers select.

Comment: Then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(window).load(function(){
      var selectedServer = '<%= session.getAttribute("selectedServer") %>';
      or
      var selectedServer = "<s:property value="%{#session.selectedServer}" />";
      ...
      $('#servers').val(selectedServer);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just exactly what I needed. Aleksandr M, How can replace the scriplet?, I tried $.session.get('selectedServer'), ... but did not work...

Comment: `var selectedServer = "<s:property value="%{#session.selectedServer}" />";` can be used

Comment: Thanks that's right, but the syntax is a little bit different=>>          var selectedMarket = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedServer}'/>";